# Routing uPnP over USB to ethernet on Ubuntu

Tags: usb

My phone has a uPnP server app ([MirrorLink](http://telematicsnews.info/2012/08/26/japan-panasonic-launches-mirrorlink-for-android-phone-and-toyota-head-unit_ag3261/)) that should connect to an in-car dash via USB. However, for testing out I have downloaded the [Nokia Qt Client](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-in-use/qterminalmodeclient), but as far as I can tell from the source code it only tries to find the client over Wi-Fi. How would I go about re-routing the USB to Ethernet so that the client can find the USB cable?

I've seen various solutions for tethering, but they involve using a proxy on the mobile device to re-route on the mobile Wi-Fi to USB, but the mobile app directly talks to USB.

(I'd like to create uPnP and MirrorLink tags, but I don't have the rep yet...)